# How to set browser cache to expire after one day?

Tags: apache, cache-control

I'm using the code below in my .htaccess file to enable caching for my website:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

In that code, you can see that the cache expiration time is set as 1 year for some file types and 1 month for others. **What I need is to make it expire after a single day.** I have already tried to replace it by "1 day" and "24 hours", but neither of those work.

Comment: "already tried to replace it by `"1 day"`" - Was that literally `"1 day"` or `"access 1 day"`? `"1 day"` is certainly an error as you are missing the _base_ (ie. `access` or `modification`) - this would have resulted in a 500 error. However, `"access 1 day"` should work - the `plus` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be as simple as missing one keyword that is causing your issue.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```